# webpack vue.js hot reload config needed for custom build setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension, hot-reload

I have a custom build setup for chrome extension which injects iframe to webpages, and this iframe is built using vue.js.
Entry point for building this iframe is `src/popup/js` and it should output to `dist/popup`.

This all works fine, but I don't know how to setup hot reload so I can see the changes in browser the moment I make changes in code.
Currently, when I run `build` step, everything is prepared and placed into `dist` folder, and iframe I want to hot reload is `dist/popup/popup.html` file.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "extensionname",
    "version": "1.0.17",
    "description": "Chrome Extension",
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
        "prettier": "prettier \"src/**/*.{js,vue}\"",
        "prettier:write": "npm run prettier -- --write",
        "build-zip": "node scripts/build-zip.js",
        "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production TARGET_ENV=production webpack --hide-modules && cross-env NODE_ENV=production TARGET_ENV=production npm run build-zip",
        "build:store": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production TARGET_ENV=store webpack --hide-modules && cross-env NODE_ENV=production TARGET_ENV=store npm run build-zip",
        "build:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development TARGET_ENV=development webpack --hide-modules && cross-env NODE_ENV=development TARGET_ENV=development npm run build-zip",
        "build:test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development TARGET_ENV=test webpack --hide-modules && cross-env NODE_ENV=development TARGET_ENV=test npm run build-zip"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "emoji-mart-vue": "^2.6.6",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vuetify": "^1.5.4",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1",
        "split-sms": "^0.1.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
        "@types/chrome": "^0.0.74",
        "archiver": "^3.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.3",
        "core-js": "^2.6.5",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "ejs": "^2.6.1",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
        "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
        "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
        "prettier": "^1.14.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "webpack": "^4.20.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
    }
}
```

This is `webpack.config.js` :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const { version } = require('./package.json');

const config = {
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: {
        'popup/popup': './popup/popup.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loaders: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?emitFile=false',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            global: 'window',
            'process.env.TARGET_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.TARGET_ENV)
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'images', to: 'images' },
            { from: 'scripts', to: 'scripts' },
            { from: 'css', to: 'css'},
            { from: 'popup/popup.html', to: 'popup/popup.html', transform: transformHtml },
            {
                from: 'manifest.json',
                to: 'manifest.json',
                transform: content => {
                    const jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
                    jsonContent.version = version;

                    if (process.env.TARGET_ENV != 'store') {
                        jsonContent['content_security_policy'] = "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'";
                        jsonContent['key'] = '123456';
                    }

                    return JSON.stringify(jsonContent, null, 4);
                },
            },
            {
                from: 'config.json',
                to: 'config.js',
                transform: content => {
                    return transformConfigForExtension(content);
                },
            },
        ]),
    ],
};

if (config.mode === 'production') {
    config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"',
            },
        }),
    ]);
}

function transformHtml(content) {
    return ejs.render(content.toString(), {
        ...process.env,
    });
}

function transformConfigForExtension(content){
    let extensionConfig = JSON.parse(content.toString())[process.env.TARGET_ENV];
    return 'const config = ' + JSON.stringify(extensionConfig, null, 4);
}

module.exports = config;
```

And this is my project structure:

[image: And this is my project structure:]

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible on Chrome. Take a look at [web-ext](https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext). It allows you to hot-reload code while developing an extension on Firefox.

Alternatively, you can also create your own extension that takes advantage of the [management API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management) to reload an extension. I'm guessing this is what web-ext does in the background.

Comment: I think that extension context can be stripped away in this question, I just want to be able to do live reload of `popup.html` page, so whenever I change some code in `components` folder, it shows it in browser.

Comment: The popup.html is part of the extension. The only way to hot reload the popup file is to reload the extension as a whole. Here's a simple test. Load your code, and delete all of the JavaScript code and save the file. It won't affect the running extension. As a consequence, you need to come up with a way to reload the extension.

Comment: You're not following me here :) I'm building just `popup.html` with Vue.js which is an iframe I embed later with my chrome extension. I don't want to load extension at all while testing this page I'm building with vue.js. But my build process puts this `popup.html` file along with other extension resources like manifest.json etc. into `dist` folder.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the response you want, but if you purely want to hot-reload this page outside of the context of the extension so you can continue to develop it, assuming you're using vue-cli v3, you could just run `npm run serve` and have it do its thing. You will have to modify your App.vue to be a wrapper-app to set it up with all of its properties, and you may have to fake a good chunk of the `chrome.extension`, `chrome.runtime` API if you want to simulate behavior inside the extension. That's what I did while developing my extension which has a Vue app being loaded inside of an iframe.

Comment: No I'm not using `vue-cli v3`